# how to modify https traffic in google chrome using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, intercept

Like a question, of course I didn't do it because of illegal behavior.

For example, I have a link: `https://example.com/inj.php`
The result I get for example is:

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

How can I fix it using only nodejs code?

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<h2>inject</h2>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to create a proxy and that device needs to install and configure your self-signed CA.
I wrote a library for personal use, it works pretty well

```
npm i pms-proxy
```

As your question above, it can be written as

```
const https = await PPCa.generateCACertificate();
const spki = PPCa.generateSPKIFingerprint((<PPCaFileOptions>https).cert);
const userData = path.join('C:/test-chrome');

const server = new PPServerProxy({https});

const pass = new PPPassThroughHttpHandler();
pass.injectBuffer((req, buffer) => {
    return {
        data: buffer.toString() + "<h2>inject</h2>"
    };
})
server.addRule().url('https://example.com/inj.php').then(pass);

await server.listen(1234);

// node module
child_process.exec(
    `start chrome --proxy-server="http://127.0.0.1:1234" --ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list=\"${spki}\" --user-data-dir=\"${userData}\"`
);
```

If you don't want to use SPKI Fingerprint you can create a self-signed CA, follow the README in the package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pms-proxy